# My iPhone won't download certain free apps

Tags: iphone

My App Store keeps saying this item is free in the store, that this item will be added to your purchases, and will be available even if your family sharing status changes. And it then says cancel or download.

I click download and it won't download and keeps popping up the same message over and over again. How do I make it stop? I can't download certain free apps.

Comment: Ok thanks tetsujin.. Hopefully that's all it is ☺️

Answer (score 0):

Go to your iTunes account, manage your hidden and downloadable apps and unhide the app you want to download again.

1. Open iTunes
2. Select 'Store' menu option --> 'View Account'
3. Look in section iTunes in the Cloud
4. Look for subsection 'Hidden Purchases'
5. Click on the 'Manage' link
6. Press the 'Apps' button
7. Find the App you are trying to download from the list
8. Click 'Unhide'

You can now download app from App Store on your iPhone.

Comment: Hi Georgia. My iTunes account has nothing in there about my apps?

Comment: There is no subsection called hidden purchases.. When I get to iTunes in the cloud it just gives me the option to remove this device...